# querying Virtuoso RDF from Pentaho (Kettle)

Tags: rdf, pentaho, virtuoso, pentaho-spoon, openlink-virtuoso

I'm trying querying a Virtuoso (RDF-store) graph from Pentaho. I do it with pentaho-step "Execute SQL script" (with this pentaho step I do insertions in the same RDF-graph) in this way,

[image]

I get launch execution but I get a columns of 0's in the output field (that I have named "output", showed in the image).
In a simmilar way I do data insertions ("INSERT DATA" in place of "SELECT") without problems, but I have troubles to get the output.

Someone knows this problem? maybe querying SQL? How could I querying Virtuoso from Pentaho?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: At first glance, this appears likely to be a data issue. What happens when you execute that SPARQL query directly against Virtuoso through its SPARQL endpoint? Are all elements of your setup (Virtuoso server, Virtuoso ODBC driver, Pentaho app, etc.) running current versions?

Comment: On Virtuoso the query works (obviously, substituing the "?" for another string). Relative to versions, I can say you that "INSERT DATA" works very well... The problem was that i got a zeros column resultset (I defined, how you can see in image, a variable named "output")...